# Why combine col and col-lg-x when using grids in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap. I saw an example on the official website as follows:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col col-lg-2">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-auto">
      Variable width content
    </div>
    <div class="col col-lg-2">
      3 of 3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-auto">
      Variable width content
    </div>
    <div class="col col-lg-2">
      3 of 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My question is why does `col` need to be included with `col-lg-2` (the line `<div class="col col-lg-2">`) ? I thought just `col` on its own means it's auto equal width, but here we are specifying `2` of `12` units of size, doesn't this just override the auto width anyway?

Answer (score 0):

As it's stated in official documentation, `col` without numbered class is used to automatically resize your columns. With `col-lg-2` you're saying to Bootstrap, that on large screens and so on it's width should be only 2 cols. You can also set col width automatically including one col with just another width, like your example above. More on this is [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/#setting-one-column-width).

You can read more about this on [official site](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns).